# Declaring a method of class type?

Tags: java, methods

I'd define myself as a beginner in Java, had it for just one semester and before that I had very little experience with programming whatsoever, virtually none with OOP.

Anyway, I'm going through a code and I found a method declared as a class type

```
public Polica stavi (Predmet p, int i)
        throws GPolIndeks, GPolZauzeto, GPolTezina{
        if(i<0 || i>=niz.length) throw new GPolIndeks (i);
        if(niz[i] != null) throw new GPolZauzeto (i);
        if(q + p.Q() > maxQ) throw new GPolTezina (p);
        niz[i] = p;
        q += p.Q();
        return this;
    }
```

Now the code is rather simple and almost I'm not stranger to it, except for the part where a method called **"stavi"** is declared. I've been thought there are two types of methods, those who return a value and those who don't, and this one does, but it is not declared as an any type regularly used (int, double, long...), it is declared with a class name, which in this case would be **"Polica"**. This is the first time I'm coming to something like this and it works in a compiler, **so my question would be, where can I read up on methods more in more detail, to better understand how this works.**

Comment: In this case the method returns a value, and the value is nothing but an object of the class `Polica`.

Comment: You must have seen and used other methods like that. `String.substring()` for example. Or `Integer.toString()`. Those methods return an object which is of the type declared (String, in these cases). Your method is no different. It returns an object of type Polica.

Comment: well the thing you want to understand is about OOP, `Polica` is class and a class is used to create an Object and Object is a part of the concepts of OOP that you must understand

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I will explain some points for you. And its all about OOP

`Polica` is a class which will became an `Object` as soon as you create an instance of it

```
Polica polica = new Polica();
```

and **methods** can return any type of variables and **also Objects**

which means in your function you're expecting to return an Object `Polica`

```
 public Polica stavi(){
   Polica polica = new Polica();
   return polica;
 }
```

and `this` represents its self instance of its own so it would be really same with this

```
public Polica stavi(){
       Polica polica = new Polica();
       return this;
}
```

Well its nice that you have a great curiosity! here's a good tutorial for you.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

The return type does not have to be a int, long or double etc. It can be of an object you define yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> it is not declared as an any type regularly used (int, double, long...), it is declared with a class name

There is no difference between int, double, long, etc. (which are called primitives) and classes when you return them. They return the same way, and a different type is returned.

```
public Potato weirdMethod(Elephant e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    return new Potato();
}
```

That would work fine if you defined the classes "Potato" and "Elephant."

(Edit: as Chris McCabe clarified in the comments, when you return an object it is pass-by-reference, so you can change it and it will change the actual object you returned. Primitives are pass-by-value so if you get a primitive from a method and change it, the original will be unaffected.)

In this case, looks like you want to be using a constructor. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: This answer is wrong and misleading, there is a significant difference between returning a built in type and returning an object reference. The mechanics of returning them are the same but the implications are very different.

Comment: @ChrisMcCabe They work the same way but just a different type is returned. I clarified that.

Comment: That is incorrect, they are both returned as a value, this means that when you return an object you return a reference to that object meaning you can edit the state of that particular object. When returning a primitive you still receive the value returned which means you essentially get a copy of the primitive not the same actual primitive. Same mechanics, very different results!

Comment: @ChrisMcCabe well, they both return the same way though, which is what I am trying to tell the question asker. You can change a method that returns an int and make it return a String, change your return statement, and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the [Java Tutorials for Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

In this example, the method is returning a *reference* to an object which in this case is the object you just invoked a method on.  This is used for chaining and a class where is often using is StringBuilder eg.

```
String text = new StringBuilder().append("Hello, the time is ")
                                 .append(new Date()).append("\n).toString();
```

As you can see, this works because each append method return `this` of the original StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

In java or any other oops language the return type of a method can be any object type i.e it is not restricted to be of primitive type ( int, double...)

You should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) (language specification) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) you can find what you need. and answering to your question this method returns an object of type Polica.

Answer (score 0):

The official [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) are a great place to start with more-ever I would recommend books like [Head First Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208) which are really good for java beginners and will help you get a grip on java fundamentals.

Being Specific to your question java methods can return either primitives like int,float etc.,inbuilt Class object instances like [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) , or custom classes that you create in your java application like  "Polica " which you have mentioned above.

Also note that within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using 'this'.So in your case when your method returns 'this' and method signature says it returns 'Polica' that means that the method "stavi" is part of the Class 'Polica'and is refering to the current instance of 'Polica'.